# How can i pile balls in a box starting from the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do like a stack of balls inside a box (div/container) but when I try the balls start to stack from the top, and I want the same thing but starting from the bottom of the box.

Here is the HTML & CSS code:

```css
#target1 {
  width: 205px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(30, 87, 212);
  border-top-color: white;
}

.prueba {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='target1'>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
</div>
```

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTq2d.png)

Comment: Flexbox feels like the best solution here. Have you explored it?

Comment: Do you want them to stack like balls do (ie not in simple rows but alternate and slight overlap) or do you want them like your snippet gives at the moment but from the bottom?

Comment: Yeah! Like balls do but in rows. You put balls in a row until the row reaches the limit of the box (width) and then another row starts above the previous one and so on until you reach the height of the div.

Comment: So do you want the balls to be touching (as they would be in real life) or do you want gaps between them (as you have in your snippet)?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this work ?

```css
#target1 {
  width: 180px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(30, 87, 212);
  border-top-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row ;
}

.prueba {

  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom : 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='target1'>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
  <div class='prueba'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean, i want the balls at the bottom but the stack needs to be in the opposite way. The 4 balls first and then the other 2 balls above.

Comment: changed it . check it out now. @Sergio2405

Comment: OH! That works perfect. Thank you so much! @Saikat Roy

Answer (score -2):

Css likes to fill that way. You could try just accepting that and use a transform to turn the box upside down.